# Pandas: Keep values in a set of columns if they exist in another set of columns in the same row, otherwise set it to NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a couple of columns in my dataframe that have values in them. I want to only keep those values in those columns if they exist in another set of columns in the same row. Otherwise, I want to set the value to `NaN`.

Here's an example dataframe:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1  30   1  29
1   5  42  99   5
2  64  67  12  22
3   2  22  22   0
4  43   6   9  43
```

In this case, I want `C` and `D` to be changed based on `A` and `B`:

```
    A   B     C     D
0   1  30   1.0   NaN
1   5  42   NaN   5.0
2  64  67   NaN   NaN
3   2  22  22.0   NaN
4  43   6   NaN  43.0
```

It's been difficult to form a query to google this, and the closest I've gotten is to use `pandas.DataFrame.isin` like this:

```
from operator import concat
first = df.head(1)
first[['C', 'D']].isin(reduce(concat, first[['A', 'B']].values.tolist()))
```

Which gives me this:

```
      C      D
0  True  False
```

Which appears to be somewhat useful, but I'm not sure if this is the right path or what to do with it from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Numpy broadcasting and `pd.DataFrame.where`

```
cd = df[['C', 'D']].to_numpy()
ab = df[['A', 'B']].to_numpy()

df[['C', 'D']] = df[['C', 'D']].where((cd[..., None] == ab[:, None]).any(axis=2))

df

    A   B     C     D
0   1  30   1.0   NaN
1   5  42   NaN   5.0
2  64  67   NaN   NaN
3   2  22  22.0   NaN
4  43   6   NaN  43.0
```

---

#### Less Numpy

```
df[['C', 'D']] = [
    (c if c in ab else np.nan, d if d in ab else np.nan)
    for *ab, c, d in zip(*map(df.get, df))
]

df

    A   B     C     D
0   1  30   1.0   NaN
1   5  42   NaN   5.0
2  64  67   NaN   NaN
3   2  22  22.0   NaN
4  43   6   NaN  43.0
```

Same thing but more specific with the columns

```
df[['C', 'D']] = [
    (c if c in ab else np.nan, d if d in ab else np.nan)
    for *ab, c, d in zip(*map(df.get, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']))
]
```

Comment: what does `any(2)` do here. (for my info)

Comment: @anky_91 I've edited the post.  It's `axis=2`.  My equality check creates a 3D array and I'm checking if any are True along the 3rd dimension.

Comment: ahh, i didnt have idea about the second axis support in `any()` :) Thank you

Comment: Thanks, this appears to work in my example. I need to take some time to understand it to apply it to my use case. Could you explain what the `**` and the `...` are doing?

Comment: @PeterTran I removed them to avoid confusion.  They are used for unpacking dictionaries as key word arguments in a function.

Comment: @piRSquared thanks. It took a little while, but I think I understand how this works. Wow, I really need to take a deep dive into numpy, it's so useful!

Answer (score 2):

You need two masks, with `A` and `B` and `OR` between them.

```
m1 = df[['C', 'D']] == pd.DataFrame({'C':df['A'], 'D':df['A']})
m2 = df[['C', 'D']] == pd.DataFrame({'C':df['B'], 'D':df['B']})
df[['C', 'D']] = df[['C', 'D']][(m1 | m2)]
```

Output:

```
    A   B     C     D
0   1  30   1.0   NaN
1   5  42   NaN   5.0
2  64  67   NaN   NaN
3   2  22  22.0   NaN
4  43   6   NaN  43.0
```